# Replacing some files before packaging system folder to system.img

Tags: android, android-source, android-make

As the title is self-explanatory, I'd want to replace some files in `system/bin/` and `system/lib/` right before when the `system.img` is being generated.

To be more exact, I've got some prebuilt `.so` files which shuold be copied over the existing ones. For example `libart.so`. Please note that replacing `art/` (source code of art) with the modified art source code is *not* an option.

To do this, which `mk` file should I investigate and put my replacing code into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may follow the same structure as the one proposed in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44503656/2969535), but use this macro:

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
     device/common/my_bin.bin:cache/my_bin.bin \
     device/common/my_so.so:system/art/my_so.so
```

This works as follows:

- The file is copied from left to(:) right.
- When the image is generated, in this case `cache` or `system`, it would be generated with the files contained in those folders.
- As we have copied our files to that destination, when `system.img` is generated, our file will be contained.

Also, the order in which this files are copied, matters. For instance if you are copying a file that already exists, hence, you want it replaced. (As your `libart.so`), you would need YOUR call to that copy to be done before the default one.

For this, I recommend doing:

- `source build/envsetup.sh`
- `lunch <<device>>`
- `mgrep libart.so` -> This does a grep through `mk` files, so you can see where the default copy is done.
- Insert `$(info whatever)` calls in desired `mk` files to trace where is a good spot to add your `PRODUCT_COPY_FILES`.

It's not easy to answer where to add it. I have never modified `libart.so` myself, but I have copied many files this way and it works like a charm.

I hope it works for your case as well.

Answer (score 1):

A quick dirty way to this:

1. Copy desired files to out(..)/system/lib or wherever after system.img has been built
2. `make snod`

Other way is using Android.mk. Create a new dir in device tree eg `libart-prebuilt`. Put here your lib, then create an Android.mk file with content

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libart-prebuilt
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT)/lib
LOCAL_MODULE_STEM := libart
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(TARGET_SHLIB_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libart.so
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARIES

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Now just add `libart-prebuilt` to `PRODUCT_PACKAGES` in your device.mk

Answer (score 0):

Also there's an option to add binary .so library as a product package, using `PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY` option in .mk file: [Include prebuilt shared library in Android AOSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300779/include-prebuilt-shared-library-in-android-aosp) or `BUILD_PREBUILT` https://stackoverflow.com/a/25682674/1028256